# Listview is not updating based on ObservableCollection properties

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, mvvm, binding

I have a BLE application, which connects to devices and aims to receive a device state dynamically in a listview.I have implemented the Native device class as a model and my viewmodel is seperate in the MainViewModel class. I have implemented INotifyPropretyChanged on both classes but the state of the device is not changing after I connect to it. It should be Disconnected, Connecting, Connected,Disconnected and I have a property of Name DeviceState from this BLE plugin that holds this values + I have implemented a INotifyPropretyChanged for it. I have tried both withoud TwoWay and with it, NotifyCollectionChanged etc. I get the device name and state(Disconnected) successfully but when I connect to it the State should change and it doesnt. It successfully connects and I have tried it on another app without MVVM approach and it gets the states after connecting , but i have to iterate through them in a loop and add them to a separate collection, which is not really efficient. Any help would be appriciated, thank you in advance!

```
class NativeDevice : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string deviceNameValue = String.Empty;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private DeviceState states;


        public NativeDevice(string name, DeviceState stated)
        {
            deviceNameValue = name;
            states = stated;
        }
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.deviceNameValue;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.deviceNameValue)
                {
                    this.deviceNameValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        
        public DeviceState States
        {
            get
            {
                return states;
            }

            set
            {
                this.states = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
       


    }
```

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<IDevice> BluetoothDevices { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<NativeDevice> devicesFound;
        public ObservableCollection<NativeDevice> DevicesFound { get { return devicesFound; } 
                                                              set { devicesFound = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private readonly IAdapter _bluetoothAdapter;
        public AsyncCommand ScanForDevices { get; }
        public AsyncCommand ConnectToDevices { get; }

        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ScanForDevices = new AsyncCommand(PerformScanAsync);
            DevicesFound = new ObservableCollection<NativeDevice>();
            BluetoothDevices = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
            _bluetoothAdapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
            _bluetoothAdapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
            {
                BluetoothDevices.Add(a.Device);
            };
            ConnectToDevices = new AsyncCommand(ConnectAsync);
            CancellationToken token = source.Token;
            devicesFound = new ObservableCollection<NativeDevice>();
        }



        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        
        async Task PerformScan{
         await _bluetoothAdapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();

            foreach (var item in BluetoothDevices)
            {
                if (item.Name == "GP")
                {
                    DevicesFound.Add(new NativeDevice(item.Name, item.State));
                }
            }
            await _bluetoothAdapter.StopScanningForDevicesAsync();
        }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:bleappmodelview="clr-namespace:BleAppModelView.ViewModels" xmlns:bleappmodelview1="clr-namespace:BleAppModelView.Model" x:DataType="bleappmodelview:MainViewModel"
             x:Class="BleAppModelView.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <bleappmodelview:MainViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
       
        <Button x:DataType="bleappmodelview:MainViewModel"
                Text="Scan"
                Command="{Binding ScanForDevices}"
                Margin="10" />
        <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding DevicesFound}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label x:DataType="bleappmodelview1:NativeDevice" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Label x:DataType="bleappmodelview1:NativeDevice" Text="{Binding States, Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="Red"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:DataType="bleappmodelview:MainViewModel"
                Text="Connect" 
                Command="{Binding ConnectToDevices}"
                Margin="10"/>
    </StackLayout>


</ContentPage>
```

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
```

```
namespace Plugin.BLE.Abstractions
{
    public enum DeviceState
    {
        Disconnected = 0,
        Connecting = 1,
        Connected = 2,
        Limited = 3
    }
}
```

```
 async Task ConnectAsync()
        {
            foreach (var device in BluetoothDevices)
            {
                if (device.Name == "GP")
                {
                    var parameters = new ConnectParameters(forceBleTransport: true);
                    await _bluetoothAdapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device, parameters, source.Token);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is.  Are you saying that when a new device is added it does not show the correct state?  Or that after it is added it is not updating when the state changes?  Also, you initialize both `devicesFound` and `DevicesFound`, you should only be updating the public property, not both.

Comment: Whenver I connect the state is supposed to change from Disconnected to Connecting and Connected but it stays on Disconnected, so its not updating the property. The initial state is correct when the device is first added

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that will update the state after the initial connection

Comment: I have a method that connects to the devices. Once it connects the state should change, its connecting properly but the state isnt changing, I thought I binded it correctly to the property

Comment: But you did not post that code

Comment: because Its not relevant to the Mvvm problem it just uses the Ble library to connect to each element from the observable collection

Comment: Your entire question is “why is the state value not updating the UI?” so seeing the code that actually updates State seems very relevant

Comment: async Task ConnectAsync()
        {
            foreach (var device in BluetoothDevices)
            {
                if (device.Name == "GP")
                {
                    var parameters = new ConnectParameters(forceBleTransport: true);
                    await _bluetoothAdapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device, parameters, source.Token);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Are you able to find something wrong with the code as a whole or...

Comment: how is anything in that code able to cause an update to the `NativeDevice` object that your `ListVIew` is bound to?

Comment: I cant call connectasync to the Native device object, because the method requires an object of type IDevice to be passed in order to connect, but if I pass an IDevice I wont be able to use binding and etc... IDevice is a part of the ble library. Do you think there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the object your UI is bound to when the connection state changes

there are a LOT of different ways to approach this, one simple one would be

```
  async Task ConnectAsync()
    {
        foreach (var device in BluetoothDevices)
        {
            if (device.Name == "GP")
            {
                var parameters = new ConnectParameters(forceBleTransport: true);
                await _bluetoothAdapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device, parameters, source.Token);

                // find the matching device in DevicesFound
                var d = DevicesFound.Where(x => x.Name == device.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                d.States = DeviceState.Connected;
            }
        }
    }
```